# Creating Flex 3.5 components with Flash CS5

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, components, flash-cs5

Is there a way to create components compatible with Flex 3.5 by using Flash CS5? I'm stumped. Whenever I run the "Convert Symbol to Flex Component" command and then try to use the resulting .swc file in a Flex 3.5 app, I get multiple instances of the following error:

> 1046: Type was not found or was not a
>   compile-time constant: Matrix3D.
>   1046: Type was not found or was not a
>   compile-time constant: Vector3D.

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you are seeing are usually brought on by a version mismatch between the Flex SDK that the SWC was compiled against and the Flex SDK of your project.

When creating SWCs using the Flash Pro interface, I'm not sure if they can be used in Flex.  Generally SWCs are not sharable between Flex and Flash.  People either recompile the source code or generate a SWF and embed it or load it using a SWFLoader.

If you're using the Flex Component Kit for Flash make sure you're using the same kit that came with the SDK you plan to target.

Comment: we use dozens of flash pro SWCs in our Flex application. It works really well, actually. So, I'm guessing it's safe to say that it's *possible* to share SWCs between Flex and Flash :).

Comment: @gmale I've been experimenting w/ this recently too.  If you use the Flex Component Kit for Flash, you can make library elements useable in Flex, and when you publish, you can embed that SWF in a Flex app, referencing library elements directly.  But, I haven't not tried to create an ActionScript / class based SWC from Flash Pro. [I don't even know how].  Do those work too?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found a work around, though. You need to create the component using Flash Builder by dragging a Flash Professional Component onto your application. (You must be in Design Mode to do this.) Then, in the properties sheet, there will be a button labeled "Create In Flash Professional..." Clicking this button will create a Flash Document with all the correct frameworks and sdks and launch Flash Professional.